# how to get rid of side scroll bars

Tags: html, css, height, width

How to see to a div class = "container" I assigned height 100vh and width 100vw and I assigned a background image to it. So far so good, but as soon as I insert anything else under the div class = "container" the side scroll bar appears. Why does this happen? According to my logic it shouldn't happen. It also happens if I put an inline / inline-block element under the div class = "container".

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



.container
{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("background-Home.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
    </div>

    <div>
        loremfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```html
    <style>
      *
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



.container
{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("background-Home.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.container img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
div {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494253109108-2e30c049369b?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80"/>
    </div>
        <div>
        loremfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
    </div>
```

Remove the padding-bottom on the div it was just for demonstration purposes

Comment: YT_Xaos, ok but why does this happen? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: Well when you have a lot of items(or text in an item) in the body then it makes a scrollbar, but other than that I don't know.

Comment: YT_Xaos, overflow hidden inside a body delete everything after my div class = "container". Not work!

Comment: Does the div after the container have to be at the bottom or can it be at the top?

Comment: bottom i want the div to the bottom

Comment: Done, Edited I have put three options please check them out

Comment: YT_Xaos, The goal is to set an image that takes all the background and then be able to scroll and see other content. I don't want the image to persist throughout the page. Only when I open the page do I want the full screen image, then as soon as I scroll I want to see more content without the background image.

Comment: Ok, Updated it takes up all the screen when you load it and then you scroll down and there is content

Comment: YT_Xaos,, the sidebar disappears, but the image is more than the viewport. I thought of using vh and vw just to be able to insert an image that would cover the whole viewport.

Comment: YT_Xaos, are you italian? If you are Italian maybe we think about it, du discord or whatever you want.

Comment: No I'm not Italian, why?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't speak English well. If I had been Italian it would have been easier to explain the problem to you

Comment: It seems to be working now maybe give it a try.

Comment: HEY ho risolto impostando:
`body
{
    overflow-y: hidden
}`

Comment: That's the same that I did?

Comment: ****  overflow-x: hidden;